# If-else statements nested inside a switch-statement always output the else statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm in the beginning stages of creating a tic-tac-toe game in C++, and in order to place the "pieces" on the board, I use a switch statement. Inside the switch, there are if-else statements to check if the requested space is occupied. However, whenever I input a spot, It executes the if-statement (places the piece), and then also executes the else-statement (says "Try again" and makes the player repeat their turn).

I've tried moving the 'break' statement before the else and within the if, but it seems to create more errors than it fixes. I also tried explicitly coding 'else-if' statements instead of just 'else', but it didn't work either.

**Switch-statement:**

```
bool place_pieces(int input, bool turn)
{
    bool occupied{ false };

    switch (input) {
    case 7:
        if (board[0][0] != 'x' && board[0][0] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[0][0] = 'x';
            else
                board[0][0] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[0][0] == 'x' || board[0][0] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        if (board[0][1] != 'x' && board [0][1] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[0][1] = 'x';
            else
                board[0][1] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[0][1] == 'x' || board[0][1] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        if (board[0][2] != 'x' && board[0][2] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[0][2] = 'x';
            else
                board[0][2] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[0][2] == 'x' || board[0][2] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (board[1][0] != 'x' && board[1][0] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[1][0] = 'x';
            else
                board[1][0] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[1][0] == 'x' || board[1][0] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (board[1][1] != 'x' && board[1][1] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[1][1] = 'x';
            else
                board[1][1] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[1][1] == 'x' || board[1][1] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        if (board[1][2] != 'x' && board[1][2] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[1][2] = 'x';
            else
                board[1][2] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[1][2] == 'x' || board[1][2] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (board[2][0] != 'x' && board[2][0] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[2][0] = 'x';
            else
                board[2][0] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[2][0] == 'x' || board[2][0] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (board[2][1] != 'x' && board[2][1] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[2][1] = 'x';
            else
                board[2][1] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[2][1] == 'x' || board[2][1] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (board[2][2] != 'x' && board[2][2] != 'o') {
            if (turn == true)
                board[2][2] = 'x';
            else
                board[2][2] = 'o';
        }
        else if (board[2][2] == 'x' || board[2][2] == 'o') {
            occupied = true;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
    return occupied;
}
```

**Game loop:**

```
while (!game_over) {

        x_turn = true;
        cout << "Player 1: ";
        cin >> player_input;

        place_pieces(player_input, x_turn);
        if (place_pieces(player_input, x_turn) == true) {
            draw_board();
            cout << endl;

            continue;
        }
        else {
            draw_board();
            cout << endl;
        }

        x_turn = false;
        cout << "Player 2: ";
        cin >> player_input;

        place_pieces(player_input, x_turn);
        if (place_pieces(player_input, x_turn) == true) {
            draw_board();
            cout << endl;

            continue;
        }
        else {
            draw_board();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

I want it to just display the new board with the piece added, and not say "Try again" or have the player repeat their turn.

Comment: To simplify things, if you have `if (condition) ... else if (!condition) ...` then that's the exact same thing as `if (condition) ... else ...`. No need for the `if (!condition)`.

Comment: As for your problem, it seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Step through the code (and step into the `place_pieces` function) to see what happens, and what the values of all involved variables really is (like the elements of `board`). A possible hint about the root of the problem: How do you initialize `board`? Are you sure the values are what you think they are?

Comment: Lastly another note about your code: All the cases in your `switch` are doing the exact same thing (just with different indexes), so you should probably think about how you could break it out so you don't have to write the same thing over and over again (with possible mistakes when copy-pasting). Perhaps start with a function where you pass the indexes as arguments?

Comment: `if (turn == true)` does exactly the same thing as `if (turn)`. Most people prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can even find out the problem without debugging. A review shows that you are doing

```
        place_pieces(player_input, x_turn);
        if (place_pieces(player_input, x_turn) == true) {
```

So you first place the piece, and then, in the if statement, you call the function again. And only in the if statement your are checking the return value.

If you call your function for 2 times with the same parameter, then at the 2nd time, the place will always be occupied.

Your misunderstanding is that you think that in the if statement just the return value will be checked. But that is not true. The function will be called again.

That is a so called side effect. You should not call functions in if statements or other boolean expressions.

The solution is easy. Declare a bool variable, get the result and then check the bool in the if:

```
        bool result = place_pieces(player_input, x_turn);
        if (result) {
```

Hope this helps . . .